# Processing 1.5 Million Line File under 5 Minutes

Tags: perl, file, csv, io

After long searches on the net, I decide to ask here regarding my problem.I have a CSV file set (36 files total), coming every 5 minutes. Each file contain around 1.5 million lines. I need to process this files in 5 minutes. I have to parse this files and create required directory from them inside the storage zone. Each unique line will be then translated to a file and put inside related directory. Also related lines will be written inside related files. As you see there are lots of I/O operation.

I can finish total 12 files for around 10 minutes. Target is to finish 36 in 5 minutes. I am using PERL to complete this operation. My seen problem is system calls for i/o operations.

I want to control file handlers and I/O buffer in Perl so that I will not have to go to write to file every time. Here is where I got lost actually. Plus creating directories seems also consuming too much time.

I search CPAN ,web to find some lead that can put light on my way but no luck.  Does anybody have a suggestion in that subject ? Where should I read or how should I proceed ? I believe that Perl is more than capable to fix this issue, but I guess I am not using correct tools.

```
open(my $data,"<", $file);
my @lines = <$data>;

foreach (@lines) {
    chomp $_;
    my $line = $_;

    my @each = split(' ',$line);
    if (@each == 10) {
       my @logt = split('/',$each[3]);
       my $llg=1;

       if ($logt[1] == "200") {
           $llg = 9;
       }

       my $urln = new URI::URL $each[6];
       my $netl = $urln->netloc;

       my $flnm = md5_hex($netl);
       my $urlm = md5_hex($each[6]);

       if ( ! -d $outp."/".$flnm ) {
          mkdir $outp."/".$flnm,0644;
       }

       open(my $csvf,">>".$outp."/".$flnm."/".$time."_".$urlm) or die $!;
       print $csvf int($each[0]).";".$each[2].";".$llg."\n";
       close $csvf;   #--->> I want to get rid of this so I can use buffer      
    }
    else {
       print $badf $line;
    }

}
```

Assume that above code is used inside a subroutine and are threaded 12 times. Parameter for above code is filename .  I wanna get rid of close. Cause every time I open and close a file makes a call for system I/O which cause slowness. This is my assumption of course and I am more then open to any suggestion

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using `system()` to copy files and make directories?

Comment: Actually no, For directories I am using built in mkdir. For files I am   using open().

Comment: You are going to need to show us your Perl - you could be doing any number of inefficient things.

Comment: Could you clarify: "My seen problem is system calls for i/o operations." - how have you come to that conclusion? Have you profiled the code running a benchmark? Your requirements are a good match to using a profiling tool, although someone might spot an obvious code structure problem if you post the code (especially any innermost loops).

Comment: Have you parallelised it so each of your (likely) 4 cores gets 9 files maybe? Have you profiled your code using the excellent http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Devel::NYTProf

Comment: Are these 36 files always of the same size? Will the amount of files or size of each file change? How large is each file?

Comment: I used thread, it is using 12 Cores, 1 core for each file. No all this 36 files are not same size. They are around 1.5 million lines. It is a CSV file. Have 5 fields de limited with ";" but characters for each field are not fixed. I will post the code.

Comment: How long does it take for `cat *csv > /dev/null`?

Comment: You are opening a file for append on every single one of the 54 million lines...

Comment: Actually yes, I am not sure what can I do cause this file is not a same file. For every loop file name and location can be different or it can be same :( I mean assume that i have 10 line and this 10 lines will be saved in 3 different files but they are not in order :( so That's why i append the file for each line. This way is slow I know it, what i am looking for is to make this part faster.

Comment: How many files do you end up with after processing 54 million lines - presumably not 54 million? And what volume of data do the files from 54 million lines actually cause on disk at the end (in MBytes say)?

Comment: The reason for my previous question is that I am thinking you would be better holding the data in memory and then writing to disk all at the end. So, create a hash using the filename as the key and appending your data to the end of the hash element rather than writing to a file. Then, when you get to the end, or you feel there is enough stuff in memory, flush it all out to real disk files.

Comment: Yes, more or less exactly as @amon has done!

Comment: I will try code that Amon send. Files are around 100 to 150 MB (each).  it is around 1.5 to 2 million files for 54 million lines. It depends on how information inside the line is different from each other

Comment: I predict his code will run 20-30 times faster.... ;-) And he gets my vote.

Comment: Actually it is running faster :) Thanks really guys. I vote for Amon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems possible that you'll open the same file multiple times. If that is so, it might be beneficial to collect the information in a data structure, and only write to the files after the loop has completed. This avoids testing for existence of the same directory repeatedly, and opens each output file only once.

We should also get rid of `URI::URL` – creating a new object during each loop iteration is too expensive considering your performance requirements. If your URLs all look like `http://user:password@example.com/path/` or `https://example.com/`, we could use a simple regex instead.

```
open my $data, "<", $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my %entries;  # collect entries here during the loop

# only read one line at a time, don't keep unnecessary ballast around
while (my $line = <$data>) {
    chomp $line;

    my @each = split(' ',$line);

    if (@each != 10) {
        print $badf $line;
        next;
    }

    my (undef, $logt) = split('/', $each[3]);
    my $llg = ($logt == 200) ? 9 : 1;

    my $url = $each[6];
    my ($server) = $url =~ m{\A\w+://([^/]+)};

    push @{ $entries{$server}{$url} }, sprintf "%d;%s;%d\n", $each[0], $each[2], $llg;
}

while (my ($dir, $files) = each %entries) {
    my $dir_hash = md5_hex($dir);
    my $dirname = "$outp/$dir_hash";

    mkdir $dirname, 0644 or die "Can't create $dirname: $!" unless -d $dirname;

    while (my ($file, $lines) = each %$files) {
        my $file_hash = md5_hex($file);
        my $filename = "$dirname/${time}_${file_hash}";

        open my $csv_fh, ">>", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
        print { $csv_fh } @$lines;
    }
}
```

I also cleaned up other aspects of the code (e.g. variable naming, error handling). I moved the call to `md5_hex` out of the main loop, but depending on the kind of data it may be better to not delay the hashing.

Comment: Thanks Amon for your effort. I will try this code and feed you back. Cheers

Comment: my ($server) = $url =~ m{\A\w+://([^/]+)/};  Hi Amon, I experience a problem with that piece here, what was your purpose here to do that ?

Comment: Forget my comment please :( I found the problem

Comment: Thanks Amon, looks like This will work for me, Now I will try to put this code in parallel to see what will be the effect.

Comment: @SunerEvren The regex figures out the authority part when given a valid URI (see also the [generic URI syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Examples)). The hostname part may be an IP address. However, it will not match a bare IP address on its own. I have no idea what input you'd like to match, so I can't adapt the regex.

Comment: Input could be "hxxp://172.16.23.4", "hxxp://www.abc.com", "hxxp://www.abc.com/sasdf".  I assume your regex will not match first 2 :)

Comment: @SunerEvren fixed: `m{\A\w+://([^/]+)/}` → `m{\A\w+://([^/]+)}`